# Entity Framework - Erro?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou seguindo um tutorial de `Entity framework`: [Simple Code First Example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx) ele é bem simples, mas por alguma razão não está funcionando aqui e aparece a mensagem de erro é a seguinte:

> AspNet\Projetos\ENTITY\ENTITY\App_Data\ENTITY.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.).
>
> CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

Estou usando o SQL Server 2012.

**Minhas classes:**

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext() : base("ENTITY")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
    }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
}
```

**Método para inserir um registro no banco:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var ctx = new SchoolContext())
            {
                Student stud = new Student() { StudentName = "New Student" };

                ctx.Students.Add(stud);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

**Web.config**

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Criei outra solution com um projeto Windows Forms. Fiz a mesma coisa: instalei o entity pelo manage nuget; criei uma classe "student"; um context; também tentei inserir um registro por um evento de um botão. Agora não deu erro mas também não criou o banco no SQL Server.

**Pessoal, o problema continua acontecendo quando é uma aplicação web. No Windows Forms deu certo. Eu criei um novo projeto, mesmo adicionando a connectionString o problema continua, a mensagem é a mesma mencionada no topo. O procedimento é diferente se for um projeto web?**

Comment: Você já verificou na pasta App_Data se existe o arquivo ENTITY.mdf?

Comment: Faltou dizer a ConnectionStrings? acho que seria isso.

Comment: Não existe esse arquivo ENTITY.mdf mas o estranho é que mesmo eu criando outro projeto o erro persiste.

Comment: A ConnectionStrings não é quando você já tem o banco criado no sql server? No tutorial não falou nada de connection string.

Comment: Quando se roda direto no Visual Studio tem também @HeyJoe, exemplo: "Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true" e [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh510202.aspx)

Comment: Outro link para [leitura](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Estou vendo dois tutoriais, ambos dizem que o entity que cria o banco, tanto é que no context foi colocado o nome que é pra ser o banco no construtor.

Comment: Pode criar sim, mas, está aprendendo errado ... só foi dois links para dicas! O Correto é instalando o servidor SQLServer na maquina e rodar migration ... mas, tranquilo ...!

Comment: Estou usando o SQL Server 2012. Ambos os tutoriais de Code First não dizem para criar o banco primeiro, o context que vai fazer isso. Mas aqui não deu certo. Também já tentei o Enable-Migrations e não criou o banco. Vou tentar criar outra solution.

Comment: Eu não consegui criar o banco pelo code first, tive que criar no SQL Server e adicionar uma connectionString na aplicação. O construtor do context que foi usado para criar o banco pelo code first eu tive que remover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Houve dois problemas, o da mensagem na minha pergunta que foi resolvido após eu remover o construtor da classe de contexto:

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext() : base("ENTITY")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

O outro problema de não criar as tabelas foi resolvido adicionando uma connectionString no Web.config ou App.config.

O meu App.config ficou assim:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <!--<parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>-->
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <!--<providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>-->
  </entityFramework>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EntityContext" connectionString="Server=MeuServer; Database=teste; uid=sa; password=asda;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Então a minha pergunta é: é obrigatório colocar a connectionString ou não?

Comment: Na verdade a primeira ConnectionString já deveria funcionar (a que está na pergunta). Você habilitou o Migrations? Como está a configuração dele?

Comment: No outro caso eu havia habilitado o migrations, mas nesse novo projeto não fiz isso, só retirei algumas partes as deixando como comentários, como você pode ver no meu App.config, e acrescentei a connectionString. Na minha pergunta não tem uma connectionString, tem um defaultConnectionFactory.

Comment: Nem na apostila tinha nada de connectionString, isso me deixou maluco. Vi isso em um vídeo no youtube, o qual ainda mostrou que o nome da connectionString tem que ser o mesmo do context, se não fosse por esse vídeo eu estaria até agora sem saber o que fazer e é uma informação tão simples.

Comment: Sim, verdade, não tinha prestado atenção. A connectionString é necessária sim, por padrão no webconfig costuma ser criada uma com o nome "DefaultConnection".

Comment: O problema continua quando crio uma aplicação web. Se for windows forms dá certo. O procedimento é diferente quando é web?